# Sorting Cassandra using individual components of Composite Keys

Tags: nosql, cassandra, composite-key, hector

I want to store a list of users in a Cassandra Column Family(Wide rows).

The columns in the CF will have Composite Keys of pattern **id:updated_time:name:score**

After inserting all the users, i need to query users in a different sorted order each time.

For example, if i specify **updated_time**, i could be able to fetch the recent 10 users.

And, if i specify **score**, then i could be able to fetch the top 10 users based on score.
Does Cassandra supports this?

Kindly help me in this regard...

Answer (score 2):

> i need to query users in a different sorted order each time...
>   Does Cassandra supports this

It does not. Unlike a RDBMS, you can not make arbitrary queries and expect reasonable performance. Instead you must [design you data model so the queries you *anticipate* will be made will be efficient](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/data_model_planning):

> The best way to approach data modeling for Cassandra is to start with your queries and work backwards from there. Think about the actions your application needs to perform, how you want to access the data, and then design column families to support those access patterns.

So rather than having one column family (table) for your data, you might want several with cross references between them. That is, you might have to denormalise your data.